# combining foreach array

Tags: php, html

I have 2 arrays and I would like to create automaticlly new rows in my table based on those arrays.

My arrays looks like this:

```
$array1['name1'] = "value1";
$array1['name2'] = "value2";
$array1['nameN'] = "valueN";

$array2['name1'] = "number1";
$array2['name2'] = "number2";
$array2['nameN'] = "numberN";
```

My html table output should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>number1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name2</td>
        <td>value2</td>
        <td>number2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nameN</td>
        <td>valueN</td>
        <td>numberN</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've been working on this 2 codes, but I don't know how to combine them:

```
<?php
foreach ($array1 as $name => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    };
unset($nick, $value);
?>

<?php
foreach ($array2 as $name => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    };
unset($nick, $value);
?>
```

Maybe I could combine both array in a multidimentional array and use some kind of foreach function like this:

```
$array = array();
$array['name1']['array1'] = "value1";
$array['name1']['array2'] = "number1";
$array['name2']['array1'] = "value2";
$array['name2']['array2'] = "number2";
$array['nameN']['array1'] = "valueN";
$array['nameN']['array2'] = "numberN";
```

Any help would be apriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume both arrays have all the same keys.

```
foreach ($array1 as $name => $value) {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td><td>'.$array2[$name].'</td></tr>
}
```

It would be more straightforward if you used a two-dimensional array instead of two different arrays.